# Find duplicate between two dates with same Employee ID and same child name in vba access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a **Form** name `frmCEA1` and a **Table** named `tabsubCEA`. Field names are:

1. E_ID (which is Employee ID, number field)
2. FY (which is Financial Year, String i.e. 2014-15)
3. FChildPrFr ( Which is Claim start Date, Date ( dd-mmm-yy format))
4. FChildPrupto ( Which is Claim end Date, Date(dd-mmm-yy format))

There are also

> four fields in table (tabSubCEA)

1. EID (which is Employee ID, number field),
2. FY (which is Financial Year, String i.e. 2014-15),
3. PeriodFrom ( Which is Claim start Date, Date ( dd-mmm-yy format)),
4. Periodtill ( Which is Claim end Date, Date(dd-mmm-yy format)).

An employee can process claim single times in a financial Year for single child and he/she can claim for maximum two child. He/She can claim separate for both child or can claim as combined. He/She can also claim for previous financial Year.

I processed claim for an employee for single child in Fin.Year 2014-15 now employee is going to claim his/her second child for same financial year and I processed it successfully.

**I want to know that How can my form(frmCEA1) prevent me using (messagebox) if i goes to process claim for same information i.e. same E_ID, First or Second Child with same claim between starting and ending Period.**

I tried so much but could not success. Kindly help...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't necessarily have to be done in VBA, but that is an option. Either way, a query needs to be run to extract the number of records that match a given situation.

When an employee is being processed, run a query against that employee ID within your tabSubCEA table to find the number of records that exist for the desired financial year. However, instead of returning the actual record data, just return the COUNT of the records. If I'm understanding your situation correctly, whenever the COUNT exceeds two, then you don't want to process the employee. The easiest way would be to disable whatever "submit" button on the form.

Your query, whether a created query that references fields on the form, or via VBA would look something like this:

```
SELECT
 COUNT(*)
FROM
 tabSubCEA
WHERE
 EID = '<employee id here>' AND
 FY = '<fiscal year here>' AND
 PeriodFrom > '<application date here>' AND
 Periodtill > '<application date here>'
```

This will count the number of records that the employee in question has successfully filed during the desired fiscal year with an active claim period.

Basically, what you're trying to extract from the system is a count of the number of records that meet a specific criteria to this situation. You're going to want something similar to this to validate the number of claims an employee is making.